# How to destroy and recreate a scene in andengine correctly?

Tags: java, android, andengine

In andAngine I need to destroy a Scene in andangine and to recreate it in order to restart the game variables and listeners and gamelogic.
i use this code:

```
scene.detachChildren();
scene.clearEntityModifiers();
scene.clearTouchAreas();
scene.clearUpdateHandlers();

System.gc();
thisengine.setScene(menuscene);
```

and then I recreate the scene

```
scene = new Scene();
scene.dosomestuff
thisengine.setScene(scene);
```

Something seems to go wrong when I recreate the third time the scene. Sprites doesn't display..are distorted or something doesn't display at all. Can anyone explain to me if I correctly initialize and destroy the scene ?

Comment: Hi Claudio. I am developing a game in AndEngine and I am also struggling with exactly same problem. Did you find any solution to this problem? If yes, can you please help me?

Comment: Hi @YogeshSomani I am also struggling with same problem... Write if u find any ...

Comment: @shihab_returns : I'll inform you if I find any solution for this. I expect the same from you. :)

Comment: http://www.andengine.org/forums/tutorials/very-simple-splash-screen-alternative-t5790.html

Answer (score 4):

Personally, I would create the scene once the first time it is used.

To change the scene, do your removal stuff as you've shown, I wouldn't bother with the call to System.gc(), and then instead of creating a new Scene() - just call scene.reset(), scene.dosomestuff, etc

Creating a new Scene like you show looks like a major memory leak, or at least a possible leak.